# Searching for duplicate files with 'uniq' misbehaviour

Tags: bash, scripting, uniq

I've started to learn bash scripting only a few moths for now in need of personalized scripts to help smoother all tasks managing files on old HDD's and so on. No school, no books, just internet and trial&error. I came across with strange behaviour of 'uniq' command.

Regardless tying to filter only the duplicate files, I've managed to make 'uniq' command to displays some unique files along with the duplicates.

As I use functions, I try to assign all needed output to variables.
Here are the lines to search duplicates by size and name :

```
dup_sn_o1=$(find "${folder1_o1}" "${folder2_o1}" -mindepth 1 -path '*/lost+found' -prune  -o -not -empty -iname "*$dup_sn_p1*" -printf "'%p'\t%s\n" | sort -t$'\t' -k2n );
dup_sn_o1v=$(echo -e "${dup_sn_o1}" | tr ' ' '_' | awk -v re=${re} -v th_fg=${th_fg} -v ktb=${ktb} -v hr_fg=${hr_fg} -v cy_fg=${cy_fg} 'BEGIN{ORS="\n"; FS=OFS="\t";} {n=split($1, a, /[/]/); for(i=1;i<n;i++){printf a[i]=(th_fg a[i]"/"); a[n]=(cy_fg a[n] ktb)}; printf a[n]"\t"; print $2}' | uniq -f1 -D --all-repeated=separate | tr '_' ' ');
dup_sn_o2=$(echo -e "${dup_sn_o1}" | sed "s/\(.*' \)/'\t/"| cut -d$'\t' -f 1 );
```

from where I get the list of files chosen by name and searched for duplicates by size (dup_sn_o2) an use it in an other function to continue clarifying with 'md5sum' :

```
dup_md5_o1=$(echo -e $dup_sn_o2 | xargs md5sum 2>/dev/null ) ;
dup_md5_o2=$(echo -e "${dup_md5_o1}" | sed 's/ /_/g; s/\(__\)/\t/g' | sort $s_o | uniq -w32  --all-repeated=separate );
```

but somehow it displays some unique files along with the duplicates.
Occurance of the lines not having any duplicates of all duplicate files displayed is about 10% .

Where am i making a mistake.

And to clarify, I've renamed all the filenames containing spaces in the directories and replaced spaces with dots ( . ), so it's not about the filenames containing spaces.

I've put here the original code as in my script with all the colour codes and whistles as maybe the reason for the misbehaviour lies in there.

UPDATE: With replaceing 'uniq' with 'awk' everything in the script behaves as expected,

```
awk_dup_o1=$(find "${folder1_o1}" -not -empty -path '*/lost+found' -prune  -o -type f -printf "%s\n" | awk '_[$0]++==1' | sort -n | xargs -I{} -n1 find "${ots1_o1}" -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum;)
```

and to separarte duplicates into groups :

```
awk_sep_o1=$(echo -e "${awk_dup_o1}" | awk 'last!=""&&last!=$1{print""}{print;last=$1}';)
```

I may as well get along with my miserable life and use 'awk' instead of 'uniq' ('cos it works), but the question remains : What causes 'uniq' to behave like it does.

Comment: Your approach would fail, if you have file names contining spaces, because you process _words_ with `xargs`. BTW, to find duplicates, I think it is more reliable if you create an associative array, where the key is the MD5 and the value is the filename. If you get some MD5, you can check easily whether you already have an entry with the same MD5.

Comment: Please post an example of actual and expected output. When `uniq` gets `a_b` and `a b`, it will output both of them, but then the subsequent `tr` will turn them both into a duplicate `a b`. In any case, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). It would be better to describe _what_ exactly you are trying to implement rather than focusing the question on _how_…

Comment: @user1934428, For spaces in pathnames I did 
| tr ' ' '_' | 
and after 'uniq' command 
| tr '_' ' '
In the first variable the 'uniq' command filters by the size 
 -printf "'%p'\t%s\n" | sort -t$'\t' -k2n  | uniq -f1 -D --all-repeated=separate 
and in the second step the key is 'md5sum' by doing
echo -e $dup_sn_o2 | xargs md5sum | sort  | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate

Comment: Using `echo -e` on the output from `find` seems crazy. Try with `printf '%s\n' "$dup_sn_o1"` but that too will fail if you have file names with spaces in them. Not saving the results in a scalar variable is probably the way to go. Use an array, or just chain the commands together in a pipe. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: @Andrej Podzimek, The filenames i'm manipulating rearly consist any underscore ( _ ) in them - thats why it was chosen to replace possible spaces in filenames.  As all the filtering is based on size  and md5sum hash, I see no need to worrie about path names containing '_'
As mentioned I'm 'tying to filter only the duplicate files'.

Comment: @digerydoo My only point was that `tr _ ' '` can create more duplicates when uses _after_ `uniq` (which holds for most uses of `tr` in general).

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't do any transformation on filenames. It is unnecessary and just makes the code more difficult to maintain.

Comment: This seems awfully complicated for just asking about the behavior of `uniq` anyway. If you can [edit] to provide a [mre] I'm sure we can get this reopened, but as it stands now, you are forcing us to jump through a bunch of hoops and guess about your file names etc just to even understand what exactly you are asking.